# Как в SharedPreferences соханить Date

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences

Скажите пожалуйста, как в SharedPreferences соханить Date (Date ddd;) и потом сравнить ddd с текущей датой? Стандартная форма записи переменной SharedPreferences выглядит так, а как туда впихнуть дату?

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), newHighScore);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: Как вариант хранить строкой, а когда надо достать дату, то строку преобразуете в дату через DateFormatter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сохранить как `long`

```
Date date = new Date()

SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putLong("date", date.getTime());
editor.commit();
```

Потом сравнить два `long`'a

Comment: у меня почему то Android Studio ругается на первую строчку SharedPreferences , пишет - cannot resolve method getActivity()

Comment: @user194394 Этот код для фрагмента. В активити вызов метода `getActivity()` следует пропустить - `SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`/ Даже начинающий разработчик должен бы понимать такие простые вещи.

Comment: Всем огромное спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Нужно всего лишь знать, что `Date` - это по факту обертка над обычным `Long`. У `Date` есть метод `getTime()`, который вернет кол-во милисекунд с 1980 года (точную дату не помню). Сохраните значение, которое вернет g`etTime()`. Восстановить можно, передав в конструктор `long`, который вы достанете из `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, то возвращает кол-во миллисекунд с 00:00 01.01. **1970** по гринвичу.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, Наверно так и есть