# Как сохранить значение переменной

Tags: java, android

Как сохранить значение переменной типа `boolean`? Использую java. Может как то можно   через **SharedPreferences**?

Comment: Да, можно через SharedPreferences

Comment: [сохранить](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putBoolean(java.lang.String,%20boolean)),и соответствкнно [получить](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getBoolean(java.lang.String,%20boolean))

Answer (score 1):

Вы сами отвечаете на свой вопрос. Вбейте в google или поиск по stackOverflow 
 "SharedPreferenses", смотрите примеры и делайте что вам требуется.
 Например [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/467643/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-sharedpreferences-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-date), просто заменить `putInt` на `putBoolean`